# Html helper in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an extension method for getting a string from resource file in asp.net mvc 3

```
public static string Resource(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string expression, params object[] args)
        {

            string path = ((RazorView)htmlHelper.ViewContext.View).ViewPath;
            var fields =
                (ResourceExpressionFields)
                (new ResourceExpressionBuilder()).ParseExpression(expression, typeof(string), new ExpressionBuilderContext(path));
            return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fields.ClassKey))
                       ? string.Format((string)htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(
                           fields.ClassKey,
                           fields.ResourceKey,
                           CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture), args)
                       : string.Format((string)htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(
                           path,
                           fields.ResourceKey,
                           CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture), args);
        }
```

Here is how I use this method

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login, Html.Resource("LoginBoxLoginField"))
```

But I don't know how to use it in an action of controller

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
        {
             //how to get string from resource file using my extension method?
        }
```

For example

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, string.Empty/* should be resource string */);
```

Comment: Why would you want to do it from a Controller? The string you are going to display might as well be placed in your View otherwise you are breaking the MVC model.

Comment: To add error message in model.

Comment: Why not just add it to the View itself?

Comment: Take a look for an example of how you could pull that off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use it in the controller because you do not have an instance of HtmlHelper inside the controller. And to create an HtmlHelper instance you need a ViewContext. And you have a view context only inside a view. If you want to use this in a controller you will have to refactor it so that this helper depends only on the HttpContext and not on an HtmlHelper.

Comment: technically he could hack to create an instance of one ... but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: <<If you want to use this in a controller you will have to refactor it >> how to refactor it?

Comment: Best to just forget that route mate. It's like smoking meth,  hard to stop and ugly as hell. =P

Comment: @AlexMaslakov, that will depend on how/where you are organizing your resource files. For example in controllers it would be easier to define global resources and then rely on the strongly typed classes automatically generated. For example: `ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Resources.Foo);` where `Resources` is defined in the `App_GlobalResources` folder.

Comment: But these error strings define in App_LocalResources. I don't want to use GlobalResources because in this case using LocalResources is enough.

Comment: @AlexMaslakov, so where do you intend to place those local resource in the case of a controller?

Comment: In folder of the view: /Views/Account/App_LocalResources/myresource.resx. Do you know anything about `App_LocalResources' folder? I guess you don't.

Comment: @AlexMaslakov, what view you are talking about in a controller? This makes strictly no sense. You can use App_LocalResources folder only once a view is instantiated which obviously it isn't yet in a controller. So you can simply forget about App_LocalResources folder in a controller. ASP.NET MVC is not classic WebForms where the view (.aspx page) does everything from intercepting the request until rendering the HTML. So in classic WebForms you can rely on App_LocalResources all the time because you have an instance of a view during the entire request. In ASP.NET MVC this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a resource in project named Resource.resx, you can simply call:

```
Resource.LoginBoxLoginField
```

or

```
Resource.ResourceManager.GetString("LoginBoxLoginField")
```

This way works properly if you create another resource file called Resource.pt-BR.resx for example, and set the culture of application to pt-BR

Comment: I know about it. Read my question once again.

Comment: I understood, but you really need to use your extension method? Why don't you use this static method in both?

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login, Resource.ResourceManager.GetString("LoginBoxLoginField")) 

and

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Resource.ResourceManager.GetString("LoginBoxLoginField"));

Comment: I saw now you using your View path in the login of extension method... Sorry

Comment: Though you didn't satisfy the author's answer, you help me know what I'm looking for. Thanks Afonso França!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do because in Controller context is not decided yet what View you'll use.